# MariaDB result-set not returning correct results

Tags: sql, join, mariadb

I really need some help figuring out a query I need to run to return the following criteria:

- Don't present patients with on hold date later than today
- Don't present patients with current month 'finalized date' unless they just cane off hold
- Until the 15th of current month, don't present patients with finalized date of last month after the 23rd
- only present patients assigned to a queue
- only present a 'household patient' to it's "home" user

The date and time fields are DATETIME

Table Structure

```
patients - id, name, call_back_date, last_service_date, finalized_date, lock_status

queues - id, name, home_user_id, active

1, test, 2, 1

patient_queue - id, queue_id, patient_id

1, 1, 1

user_queue - id, queue_id, user_id, active
1, 1, 1, 1 


SELECT
    pq.patient_id
        FROM patient_queue pq
        INNER JOIN queues q
            ON pq.queue_id = q.id
        INNER JOIN user_queue uq
            ON uq.queue_id = q.id
        INNER JOIN patients p
            ON pq.patient_id = p.id
        WHERE pq.queue_id = (SELECT
            uq.queue_id
        FROM user_queue uq
        WHERE uq.active = TRUE
        AND uq.user_id = 4)
        AND p.lock_status = FALSE
        AND p.member_status = 'Enrolled'
        OR p.member_status = 'Enrollment'
        AND uq.active = TRUE
        AND q.active = TRUE
        AND p.household_id = NULL
        AND p.call_back_date <= NOW()
        OR p.call_back_date = NULL
        AND (NOW() - p.finalized_date) <= 20
        AND p.finalized_date < NOW()
        OR p.call_back_date = NULL
        AND p.finalized_date = NULL
        OR q.home_user_id = 10
        AND p.call_back_date <= NOW()
        OR q.home_user_id = 10
        AND p.call_back_date = NULL
        AND (NOW() - p.finalized_date) <= 20
        AND p.finalized_date < NOW()
        OR q.home_user_id = 10
        AND p.call_back_date = NULL
        AND p.finalized_date = NULL
        ORDER BY IF(p.call_back_date < NOW(), 0, IF(ISNULL(p.last_service_date), 0.5, p.last_service_date));
```

The results I get are not in order and if I refresh the query, it cycles like 5 times, so I would get id of 2 then 10 then 5 then 6 then 32, then it would go back to 2 and start over, so I don't know if its my callback date or if i am over thinking this query or what?

Comment: your last statement is rather gibberish. `IFNULL` would simplify the second part of the `ORDER BY`. Your where criteria is far too long based on your text description of filtering.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Show the largest subproblem that you can do correctly & the first place you get stuck extending it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Date arithmetic** is wrong:

```
(NOW() - p.finalized_date) <= 20
```

-->

```
p.finalized_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 20 DAY
```

or (to talk date only, not datetime):

```
p.finalized_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 20 DAY
```

Meanwhile, this is OK:

```
p.call_back_date <= NOW()  -- meaning that the callback dates is at or before this instant.
```

**AND vs OR**

```
a AND b OR c AND d  means  (a AND b) OR (c AND d)
```

If you meant

```
a AND (b OR c) AND d
```

then you must use parens.  That is obviously needed here:

```
    AND p.call_back_date <= NOW()
    OR p.call_back_date = NULL
    AND ...
```

-->

```
    AND (p.call_back_date <= NOW()  OR  p.call_back_date = NULL)
    AND ...
```

**IN()** - For clarity, change

```
    AND (p.member_status = 'Enrolled' OR p.member_status = 'Enrollment')
```

to

```
    AND p.member_status IN ('Enrolled', 'Enrollment')
```

(There is no difference in performance, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but I have some possible improvements that can be done that might push you forward a correct query

```
SELECT pq.patient_id
FROM patient_queue pq
INNER JOIN queues q ON pq.queue_id = q.id
INNER JOIN user_queue uq ON uq.queue_id = q.id
INNER JOIN patients p ON pq.patient_id = p.id
```

First issue here, I don't understand why this need to be a subquery. Remove it and use WHERE condition in main query

```
    WHERE pq.queue_id = (SELECT
        uq.queue_id
    FROM user_queue uq
    WHERE uq.active = TRUE
    AND uq.user_id = 4)
```

So this instead

```
   WHERE uq.active = TRUE
     AND uq.user_id = 4
     AND p.lock_status = FALSE
```

Here you are mixing AND and OR without parentheses which most likely is wrong

```
    AND p.member_status = 'Enrolled'
    OR p.member_status = 'Enrollment'
```

Should be written as

```
    AND (p.member_status = 'Enrolled' OR p.member_status = 'Enrollment')
```

Below you have the same issue with OR again but I am having a hard time understanding how to group them but since you have `OR p.call_back_date = NULL` and `OR q.home_user_id = 10` several times it is obvious you need to group them using parentheses

```
    AND uq.active = TRUE
    AND q.active = TRUE
    AND p.household_id = NULL
    AND p.call_back_date <= NOW()
    OR p.call_back_date = NULL
    AND (NOW() - p.finalized_date) <= 20
    AND p.finalized_date < NOW()
    OR p.call_back_date = NULL
    AND p.finalized_date = NULL
    OR q.home_user_id = 10
    AND p.call_back_date <= NOW()
    OR q.home_user_id = 10
    AND p.call_back_date = NULL
    AND (NOW() - p.finalized_date) <= 20
    AND p.finalized_date < NOW()
    OR q.home_user_id = 10
    AND p.call_back_date = NULL
    AND p.finalized_date = NULL
    ORDER BY IF(p.call_back_date < NOW(), 0, IF(ISNULL(p.last_service_date), 0.5, p.last_service_date));
```

Maybe relevant but notice that NOW() include a time as well so depending what is stored in your date columns comparing them to NOW() might not work as expected.

Comment: Thank you, I will make the changes and see what happens